# 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, class

I am working on WinForms using C#. I made a class video that has method `yourvideos()`. This method reads data from SQL database and add it in `imagelist` and `listview`.

First I have uploaded the image and then take the location of image using:

```
var=open.FileName.ToString();
```

Then in a function `uploadvideo()`, I converted image to bytearray and inserted it to database:

```
public void uploadvideo(string url, string path, string name,string title, DateTime date, string imgloc, string user)
        {
            con.Open();
            FileStream file = new FileStream(imgloc,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file);
                byte[] img = br.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
           cmd = new SqlCommand($"insert into RecipeInfo (RecipeName, [Recipe Link],Thumbnail,Username, Date, Title) values ('{name}','{path}','@img','{user}','{date}','{title}')", con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

and then the function `yourvideos()` where I am retrieving data comes.

```
public void yourvideos(string user, ImageList imglist, ListView list, Label l)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand($"select Title, Thumbnail from RecipeInfo where username='{user}'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[2]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            imglist.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(ms));
            list.Items.Add(reader[5].ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show("Data presesnt");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        l.Visible = true;
        l.Text = "Upload videos and share your recipes with others";
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

This function is called in the Form under the button click event

```
v1.yourvideos(Form2.setname, imageList1, yourvideoslistview, messagelabel);
```

Now, the issue is that the control enter in if statement means data is present but then it does not read data and display error:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

How can I solve this issue?
I showed a messagebox in order to confirm that the if statement is working and it worked, but data is not being retrieved.

Comment: _while(reader.Read())_

Comment: `while (reader.HasRows)` will never end :) (If it has rows) Reading the rows won't consume them.

Comment: Also consider to use as soon as possible a parameterized query. Putting the user variable inside the query text in that way opens the door to Sql Injection

Comment: Oh thank you so much

Comment: If I place it outside while then it is giving error, 'value of null is not valid for stream'. And if i place it in while it is giving the error 'index was outside the bounds of the erray'

Comment: You have `select Title, Thumbnail from RecipeInfo [...]`. So you're retrieving 2 Fields. How would you get `reader[5]` if you only have 2 Fields (`0` and `1`)? Why don't you index by Field name?

Comment: Don't we have to give the index that is in our table. Like in my table title is at index 5 and thumbnail at index 2

Comment: No, of course not. Your query returns rows from your database in the Columns you have asked for. That's your reference, not the whole database. What would happen if you had a cross-table / cross-database query? How would you determine the index of those Columns? Anyway, you can use the Column/Field name as the indexer: e.g., `reader["Title"]`. The names are those used in the query (since you could use an alias).

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not looking to fix your method in obtaining your data, as there are a number of issues here but you can get help on these in other SO Q's.

You can't return an index in position 5 when you are only selecting 2 columns of data.

```
list.Items.Add(reader[5].ToString());
```

Change this to something like:

```
list.Items.Add(reader["Title"].ToString());
```

Substitute 'Title' for anything else in your SELECT statement.

I would also change:

```
while (reader.HasRows)
```

To

```
while(reader.Read())
```

**EDIT**
In order to fix up part of your SQL statement which will not work, I would suggest using a SQL Command Parameter. First, update this part of your Query.

```
username='{user}'
```

to this

username = @username

Next, you will need to set this as a command parameter by adding the following on the line before con.Open().

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
```

Comment: I have made all the changes but there is a new error 'parameter is not valid '. In my database I have made the datatype for Image as image.

Comment: Check my Edit on original post for another thing you should update. This could be the parameter it is complaining of, however if not can you please post a little bit more detail to help troubleshoot.

Comment: I am included more details

Comment: I have changed it to parametrized query but still same error